# SwiftUI - new child view created but body property not called

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI view hierarchy with a parent (`Lifecycle`) and a child (`ChildView`). The child gets recreated when a `@State` variable changes. Each time the child is recreated, I create a helper class (`BusinessLogic`) and pass that to the initializer of the `ChildView`.

My problem is that the `ChildView` never (visibly) updates the second time (onwards) that it is created.

The below is a simplified version of my real code which exhibits the problem:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

protocol BusinessLogicDelegate {
    func receiveString(str: String)
}

class BusinessLogic {
    let str: String
    var delegate: BusinessLogicDelegate?
    
    init(str: String) {
        print("Creating new business logic")
        self.str = str
    }
    
    func sendString() {
        // In the real world the business logic would modify
        // `str` in some complicated way...
        let newStr = "Performed complicated modification of: \(str)"
        self.delegate?.receiveString(str: newStr)
    }
}

struct SubView: View, BusinessLogicDelegate {
    let businessLogic: BusinessLogic
    @State var displayMe: String
    
    init(businessLogic: BusinessLogic) {
        print("Creating new SubView")
        self.displayMe = "PREFIX: \(SubView.randomString(length: 10))"
        self.businessLogic = businessLogic
        self.businessLogic.delegate = self
    }
    
    static func randomString(length: Int) -> String {
        let letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
        return String((0..<length).map{ _ in letters.randomElement()! })
    }
    
    func receiveString(str: String) {
        print("Received string from business logic: \(str)")
        // Something is wrong here. display me doesn't get assigned here. It
        // retains its old value.
        // N.B. This is _not_ actually what I was posting about originally.
        // This is a second issue I now have as a result of creating this
        // example code.
        displayMe = str
        print("Stored string in SubView is now: \(displayMe)")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        let _ = print("body recomputed for SubView")
        // The PREFIX logic here is just for debugging. I want to be able to identify
        // new instances of this struct and also have a way to only run the business
        // logic once when the view is created.
        if !displayMe.hasPrefix("PREFIX") {
            Text(displayMe)
        } else {
            Text(displayMe).onAppear() {
                // Note that onAppear is never called after the first time around
                print("onAppear called for SubView")
                Task { @MainActor in
                    businessLogic.sendString()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Lifecycle: View {
    @State private var str: String = ""
    
    // body will be recomputed each time the user changes the text
    // in the TextField
    var body: some View {
        TextField(
            "Enter a string",
            text: $str
        )
        .textInputAutocapitalization(.never)
        .disableAutocorrection(true)
        .border(.secondary)

        Text(str)
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
        
        if (str != "") {
            // A new SubView will be created each time the text changes along
            // with a new piece of BusinessLogic
            SubView(businessLogic: BusinessLogic(str: str))
        } else {
            // Don't do anything when the view is initially created.
            // Wait for the user to enter the first bit of text.
            Text("No business logic yet")
        }
    }
}
```

What I observe is that the first `SubView` renders and I never see any of the subsequent `SubView`s even though they are clearly initialized.

Some notes:

- I  actually have another problem which has arisen from this example code. In the `receiveString` callback, the assignment `displayMe = str` doesn't work. The value of `str` stays as it was. [This](https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/652080) seemed related, but it didn't help me fix the problem.
- In my real code (which is more complex) - the body property of the equivalent `SubView` is never actually even accessed.
- I'm aware there might be different ways to achieve certain things, e.g. instead of using `onAppear` I'm probably better scheduling a task either directly in the `body` method or in an initializer. Regardless, I'd like to understand why the code isn't working as I'd expect.
- I've searched through quite a number of similar problems and none seem to match what I'm seeing here.

In short - I'm in a mess and can't figure out if I'm hitting SwiftUI bugs or if I'm failing to understand something fundamental about how SwiftUI works.

Comment: Note, to initialise a `@State var` in `init()`, you need to use 
`_displayMe = State(initialValue: "PREFIX: \(SubView.randomString(length: 10))")`.
Also IMHO it is not a great idea to mix the delegate functionality (UIKit ) with the SwiftUI state based declarative user interface like you do, based on protocol conformance.

Comment: Normally in SwiftUI your `View` struct wouldn't have an `init` and you wouldn't have any classes. This allows diffing to work correctly.

Comment: Due to the value type nature of SwiftUI and the storage it handles “delegates” never work the same way as they do with reference types. Note that State should always be marked as private too. The “delegate” should be a reference type such as ObservableObject or Observable.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments above. Sorry for the slow reply, I was away unexpectedly last week. What you're all saying makes sense. I've taken this on board, along with the answers below, and am refactoring to be more in tune with the framework.

Comment: Note: I would love to understand really why `displayMe = str` doesn't work. I understand that I _shouldn't_ do this (according to SwiftUI programming paradigms) but I don't really know why the state change is rejected by the framework. This doesn't matter much as I'll just avoid doing it, but I kind of hate opaqueness as it limits my understanding of the rules.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference in SwiftUI between a `View` instance being created and that counting as the view "appearing". Creation of the tree of view structs happens all the time, and then SwiftUI's diffing mechanism compares the new tree with the current tree to decide what has appeared or disappeared and what just needs a `body` re-evaluation.

This is a fundamental difference to UIKit, where you create an instance of a view and that instance is the one that is then drawn on your screen, and the instance is persistent.

A single `View` could be instantiated hundreds of times in response to events elsewhere in the app, but that doesn't mean it will have `onAppear` executed hundreds of times.

Your code doesn't look like idiomatic SwiftUI and you will probably end up hitting more issues with this pattern, because you're fighting the framework. In particular, any time you are storing a reference to a `View` instance, you are almost definitely doing it wrong (for the reasons outlined above).

You can get the effect you're after by adding `.id(str)` to your `SubView`:

```swift
SubView(businessLogic: BusinessLogic(str: str)).id(str)
```

This forces SwiftUI to treat the view as "new" compared to the previous instance, because it has a different identity, but the sheer ugliness of the code should tell you it's the wrong thing to do.

`BusinessLogic` should probably be `Observable`, and expose variables that can be used as bindings or just observed by subviews. Try to keep actual business logic out of your view structs, you will be much happier.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm starting to understand the subtleties a bit more now. `onAppear` (etc) definitely aren't working how I initially envisaged.

Answer (score 1):

I think you were confused about re-rendering and view's state

1. `Text(displayMe).onAppear()`: The view itself might not need to call onAppear again, even if you saw the log `print("Creating new SubView")`
   was printed out. It depends on the SwiftUI graph. It can recognize the view identity and update the data only.

So you need to make a new view's ID every single time your `str` changes, by adding `id`. Hence, you've created a trigger to create a new view instance.

```swift
SubView(...)
    .id(str)
```

---

2. As I can see here, there is a single source of truth `str`, passing around from:

> Lifecycle -> SubView <-> BusinessLogic.

It's a bit cumbersome in your `SubView`. So, I could refactor the code above. I will make a kind of `model` that represents `displayMe` then move all the relevant generated function stuff inside this model. I'd want to insert `debounce`  because I feel like this UI is a kind of typeahead search. You also don't require the delegate pattern here.

```swift
class BusinessLogic: ObservableObject, BusinessLogicDelegate {
    @Published var text: String = ""
    @Published var debouncedText: String = ""
    @Published var displayMe: String = ""

    private var subcriptions: Set<AnyCancellable> = .init()

    init() {
        $text
            .debounce(for: .seconds(0.5), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink { [weak self] text in
                self?.debouncedText = text
            }
            .store(in: &subcriptions)
    }

    private func randomString(length: Int) -> String { ... }

    func generateRandomString() {
        displayMe = "PREFIX: \(randomString(length: 10))" 
    }

    func sendString() {
        let newStr = "Performed complicated modification of: \(text)"
        displayMe = newStr
    }
}
```

Now you don't need boilerplate initial function, it could be:

```swift
struct SubView: View {
    @ObservedObject var businessLogic: BusinessLogic

    var body: some View {
        Text(businessLogic.displayMe)
        .task {
            //Mock perform task
            try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1_000_000_000)
            businessLogic.sendString()
        }
        .onAppear {
            businessLogic.generateRandomString()
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, declaring businessLogic in Lifecycle as a @StateObject:

```swift
struct Lifecycle: View {
    @StateObject private var businessLogic = BusinessLogic()
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField(
            "Enter a string",
            text: $businessLogic.text
        )
        ...
        Text(businessLogic.text)
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
        
        if (businessLogic.debouncedText != "") {
            SubView(businessLogic: businessLogic)
                .id(businessLogic.debouncedText)
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Output. I hope it helps.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the post and apols for the slow response. I had a last min trip last week. I've taken on board what you've said (and likewise what others have said). It generally makes sense. One issue I am unclear on with your rewrite is what the canonical way is  to propagate changes back to the model. For example...

Comment: In your rewrite, in SubView, I explicitly have to call businessLogic.sendString to trigger the business logic to react to a change in it's text value. This feels somewhat clunky to me. I would like my model to react in the same way that the view does. Specifically: user triggers data change in the view -> data updates in the model -> model automatically takes new action based on that data. I feel like it shouldn't be the responsibility of the view to tell the model what to do next. Am I thinking about this the right way or am I still missing something?

Comment: I supposed BusinessLogic rather be a handler than a model. The model itself is these string fields inside BusinessLogic. And what I implemented was making data binding between BusinessLogic and View(s). Let me explain the data flow: init a SubView with a handler, make a data binding mechanism within view and`displayMe`, View will trigger actions (request API/Database etc...) to interact with `displayMe`. So `displayMe <-> SubView`. You had the right insight View shouldn't tell the model what to do next, however, it's not a model in this scenario, the model (`displayMe`) is just a part of it.

Comment: Explicitly `businessLogic.sendString` to be called from outside is pretty normal. (as you did onAppear). You might want to take a look at [Data Essentials in SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10040/). They also provided a class `CoverImageLoader` to handle loading image logic.